# React, state is not updated after a .then

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send a text/string to my server.js from an input search, which checks in my Postgres database if an item is matching my text/string.

My console.log only returns the matching items, but one "step" too late (if i write 'to', it will log only things matching with 't'). The problem does not seem to come from my server.js, as it logs the correct results. I really don't understand why my `console.log` does not work, since it is in a subsequent `.then()`, which is in my mind means that the state should have been updated.

It looks like a lifecycle issue or a misunderstanding of promises and callbacks, but I don't know where to look.

Here is the beginning of my component:

```
class ItemSearch extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            searchfield: '',
            itemlist: []
        }
    }

    searchDatabase = (search) =>{
        this.setState({ searchfield: search.target.value }, this.fetchDatabase)
    }

    fetchDatabase() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/items/search', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                searchfield: this.state.searchfield
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(items => {this.setState({itemlist: items})})
        .then(console.log(this.state.itemlist))
    }
```

I tried to log as a callback function, as I read that setState update issues can be solved by using the callback function, but it did not work (it logs nothing):

```
    .then(items => {this.setState({itemlist: items})}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.itemlist)
    })
```

My best result was when I tried to `console.log` with `componentDidUpdate`, which was sending me the previous state as well as the new state, which is not ideal I guess (making too many calls?)

Comment: Setting the state in react is async, just because the set has been called does not mean the state is updated yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a `setState` on a React component, its state is not updated immediately; instead, the component does all updates on "next tick", accumulating all `setState` calls that have been made.

In your case, if you want to make your `setState` call to pause the promise chain, you can use the following code:

```js
.then(
    items => new Promise(
        (resolve) => this.setState({itemlist: items}, resolve)
    )
)
.then(() => console.log(this.state.itemlist))
```

It will wrap your `setState` call into a promise, that will resolve after the state will be set.

Also it fixes your last `.then` call that should accept a function that has `console.log(...)` statement, but not the statement itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

> My best result was when I tried to console.log with
> componentDidUpdate, which was sending me the previous state as well as
> the new state, which is not ideal I guess (making too many calls?)

**Note:** You should always try to use **componentDidUpdate** for states comparison no matter how many API calls UI make because it provides you the better flexibility over your actions on a state update.

Comment: Thank you for this reply!
I definitely will go deep into the whole lifecycle thing asap..